# Add Domain name to Docker Cloud node

Tags: docker, docker-cloud

I have created a node cluster on Docker cloud. I have one for the website and one for the DB. I have an IP address for the website, but I would like to be able to associate a sub-domain to it.

Does anyone know how, or if I can do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can use CNAME record at your DNS manager to point to the Docker Cloud service endpoint. This can be a subdomain.

e.g.

```
xxx.xxx.xxxxxxxx.svc.dockerapp.io  - CNAME    - sub.example.com
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. You get a connection refused.

Comment: Are you able reach the raw Docker Cloud Service endpoint? Sounds to me like you don't have the correct ports open for your web app. otherwise I have successfully done this for many apps. see https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/ports/#service-and-container-dns-endpoints